# Переключение между активностями

Tags: android, activity

Если запущены несколько активностей с помощью startActivity(*intent*), то как переключаться между ними, не запуская их еще раз? Не нашел подходящего метода в документациях

Comment: А в чем проблема запуска их еще раз? Если вы боитесь, что активити создается заново, то это не так. Можете попробовать создать активить Activity1, переопределить каждый метод жизненного цикла и писать туда лог. Вы увидите, что при переходе в Activity2 будет вызван только onPause() и onStop(). То есть активити не будет уничтожена.

Comment: @Maxgmer Активити в фоне может быть уничтожена системой в любой непредсказуемый момент.

Comment: @Эникейщик это да, я противоположного не утверждал. Думаю, если бы именно это беспокоило задавающего вопрос, он бы это и спросил. Тут, как я понимаю, он хочет избежать частого пересоздания активности, поэтому я дал такой ответ. Но конечно было бы неплохо дополнить вопрос, может я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Запущенные активити остаются в стеке, вызывая `startActivity(intent)`, вы помещаете ее на вершину стека. Потом вызвав `finish()`, убираете ее из стека и система переходит к предыдущей. Это простейшая схема навигации. Понятия "переключения" между активити в Андроид нет.

Comment: возможно вам подойдут фрагменты https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=RU